# How to import JSON data to MySQL and visualize it on a web page?

Tags: javascript, mysql, mariadb

I am new to databases and need help architecting java script to visualize JSON data. The first is to import JSON to MariaDB. Retrieve this data to visualize it in a UI (a web page).

JSON -> DATABASE -> UI

I tried the "Table Data Import Wizard" to import the JSON. Sample JSON here:

```
{
  "source"= "auto",
  "version"= "1.0",
  "components"= [
    {
      "properties": {
        "exectime": "2.1"
      },
    "key": "/key/value/pair - Impl",
    "parent": "AWS"
    }
  ],
  "associations": [
    "source": "/key/value/pair - Impl"
    "target": "/target/path - Hdlr,
  ]
  "properties": {}
}
```

As there is difficulty importing it through wizard, i converted it to a CSV and imported it to database. I am seeing if there is a best way to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the database MySQL or MariaDB? Your title does not match the description.

Comment: Also, just to note, there's a lot to unpack here. Your proposed architecture is not necessarily 'conventional', so-to-speak. You shouldn't be connecting your presentational layer directly to a database. Generally data is requested and delivered through an API (ReST, GraphQL, or otherwise), and for good reason.

Comment: I connect to MariaDB using MySQL workbench.